# how to use EXTRACTVALUE() in mysql to get xmlfrag?

Tags: mysql, xml

given the xml in mysql DB  like is:

```
set @xml = '<lrb id="370" deleted="0">
<lrb id="371" deleted="0"><add/></lrb>
<lrb id="372" deleted="0"><add/></lrb> 
<add/></lrb>'
```

I use sql: `SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(@xml,'//lrb[@id=370]')`

and I want return this:

`<lrb id="371" deleted="0"><add/></lrb>
 <lrb id="372" deleted="0"><add/></lrb>`

**but the result only return some whitespaces.**

I need your help to this hardwork.

thanks.

Comment: yes,mysql5.1+ has two new funtions of operating XML-- EXTRACTVALUE and UPDATEXML:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **ExtractValue()** returns only CDATA, and does not return any tags that might be contained within a matching tag, nor any of their content (see the result returned as val1  in the following example). [details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)

If you replace it to something like :

```
set @xml = 
'<lrb id="370" deleted="0">THIS WILL RETURN
  <lrb id="371" deleted="0">bbb<add/></lrb>
  <lrb id="372" deleted="0">ccc<add/></lrb>
  <add/>
</lrb>';

SELECT TRIM(EXTRACTVALUE(@xml,'//lrb[@id=370]'));
```

return **THIS WILL RETURN**